# when is super() called in the below code

Tags: java, constructor

Trying to understand when does the super() method called. In the below code, Child class has a no-argument-constructor with this(), so compiler cannot insert super(). Then how is parent constructor called.

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        System.out.println("In parent constructor");
    }
 }


public class Child extends Parent
{
private int age;

public Child()
{   
    this(10);
    System.out.println("In child constructor with no argument");
}

public Child(int age)
{
    this.age = age;
    System.out.println("In child constructor with argument");
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("In main method");
    Child child = new Child();
}

}
```

Output :

```
In main method

In parent constructor

In child constructor with argument

In child constructor with no argument
```

Comment: this(10) can be used to invoke current class (Child) constructor only.

Comment: Could you please run your program in debug mode? It will help you to understand the output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what happens:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
        System.out.println("In parent constructor"); // 4 <------
    }
}


public class Child extends Parent
{
    private int age;

    public Child()
    {
        this(10); // 2 <------
        System.out.println("In child constructor with no argument"); // 6 <------
    }

    public Child(int age)
    {
        // 3 -- implicit call to super()  <------
        this.age = age;
        System.out.println("In child constructor with argument"); // 5 <------
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("In main method"); // 1 <------
        Child child = new Child();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`super()` is called implicitly before the first line of any constructor, unless it explicitly calls `super()` or an overload itself, or the class is `java.lang.Object.`

Answer (score 0):

Before an answer I would like to clarify a few things that I consider important for this question:

- When you do not declare a constructor for a class the Java compiler build a default constructor in compilation time.
- When we have a subclass that not calls to its father constructor. Again, Java build the default constructor for the parent and then execute the subclass' constructor (cause when a child is instanciate firstable its parent is created).

So in this case:

1) Execute public main method.
2) Instance of new child
2.1) 'Build child constructor' but first Java compiler build the default constructor for its father.
2.2) Build child (that one that no receive parameters)
3) Execute the second constructor with the age parameter from the default constructor (previous constr).

I hope that would help.